# HTML float image beside text

Tags: html, css

Im still learning on how the css works and im stuck on a simple problem. basically I have this html code

```
<div class="polaroid">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <pre>   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget imperdiet tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</pre>
    <div class="polaroid-content">
        <img src="images/babot1.jpg" alt="bobat1">
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css looks like this

```
div.polaroid{
position:relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width:99%;
background-color: white;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
padding-bottom:20px;
}
div.polaroid h1{
padding:0px 10px 0 10px;
margin-bottom:0px;
}
div.polaroid pre{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
div.polaroid-content{
float:right;
width:40%;
background-color: white;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 
0.19);
margin-right:10px;
padding-right:0;
}
div.polaroid-content img{
width:50%;
margin-bottom:-3px;
}
```

but the result is not as I expected.
Problem 1: when the text is longer the text exceed the `<div>` and extending the horizontal page.
Problem 2:If you refer to the image my image is outside the `polaroid div`
[image]

will appreciate anyones help

Comment: because you have used pre - it will format things exactly as they are inside it - you have one long line of text, that is how it will come out - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use pre in this case, just wrap yout text in a `<p>` or `<span>`, both tags are better in semantics and in the way they behave in the DOM, if you use `<span>` or `<p>` with the css float, should work!

Answer (score 0):

```
.polaroid{
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        padding:20px;
        }

    .polaroid p{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width: 70%;
    display: inline-block;
        }

    .polaroid-content{
    float:right;
    width:25%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 
    0.19);
    margin-right:10px;
    display: inline-block;
        }


<div class="polaroid">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget imperdiet tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
    <div class="polaroid-content">
        <img src="images/babot1.jpg" alt="bobat1">
    </div>
```

Comment: when I added it, the navbar is under the polaroid class